# Unable to send message over SMTP

Tags: powershell, smtp

I've a server/application that is registered in SMTP relay. when I'm trying to use the below PowerShell code shows an error

> Server configuration rejects your message from that IP address

```cs
$SMTPSvr = ‘xyz.com’
$from = ‘ben@gmail.com’
$to = 'sam@gmail.com’
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
Test-NetConnection $SMTPSvr -port "25"

Send-MailMessage –From $from –To $to –Subject “TestEmail” –Body “Testl” -SmtpServer $SMTPSvr
```

Comment: Is the machine that you are sending from allowed to send messages anonymously in the exchange relay? You can test this by sending the message with credentials. If it passes, that is your issue

Comment: Yes machine is allowed to send messages. I tried sending message using credentials, still it gives me the same error

Comment: As an aside, Never use those curly 'smart-quotes' in code. Replace them with straight ones.

Comment: The server doesn't accept your message. Check the server logs to find out why that is.